# Properly manage user sessions in Keycloak and Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, redis, keycloak, session-management

I have KeyCloak deployed to kubernetes.

When the pod restart for any reason (like a modification to the deployment) all user sessions are lost.

I see in [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#cache-configuration) that session can only be stored in-memory. While it will be replicated, I found no documentation to ensure all sessions are replicated before the old pod goes down.

Strangely, My searches don't find people having any issue with this. Am I missing something?

My ideal solution would be to store the session data in a redis cluster.

Comment: Do you have any update on this? I'm facing a similar problem. I have keycloak running on 3 nodes and the caches have 3 owners but everytime one node shuts down or I deploy new changes all user sessions are lost.

Comment: Keycloak supports infinispan out of box. If I had enough time, I liked to implement a infinispan wrapper over redis. This would enable us to use a managed redis and not maintain yet another HA subsystem. But time was ticking and we just deployed infinispan.